# GCP Bucket Recreated Empty

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

It had folders and files in a GCP Cloud Storage bucket. It was simply recreated with the same name in the same location, but empty. The stats show the normal storage volume up until yesterday, after which they are reset to zero. I checked and saw today's creation date. I didn't find logs, emails or any clues of what happened. It's just recreated empty.
I´m in GCP Storage console.
Does anyone think of a way to recover the lost data?

Comment: Were you on free trial and upgraded around that the time your data disappeared?

Comment: `I checked and saw today's creation date`. It appears that the files have been overwritten. That means you have a process/app or perhaps leaked credentials. Unless you have versioning enabled, the previous data is gone.

Comment: If the bucket has been (really) deleted and recreated, you can look at the audit log to understand which identity did the thing.